# retrofit response and proper POJO ( plain Old Java Object)

Tags: java, android, retrofit, pojo

I call service and the responses are something like this :

```
    [
    {
        "CreateDate": null,
        "Creator": 0,
        "Id": 1,
        "LastModifiedDate": null,
        "Modifier": 0,
        "Description": null,
        "Name": "test0"
    },
    {
        "CreateDate": null,
        "Creator": 0,
        "Id": 2,
        "LastModifiedDate": null,
        "Modifier": 0,
        "Description": null,
        "Name": "test2"
    },
    {
        "CreateDate": null,
        "Creator": 1,
        "Id": 3,
        "LastModifiedDate": null,
        "Modifier": 1,
        "Description": null,
        "Name": "test1"
    }
]
```

I wanna create proper Object for this so I created Two class like following :

**documentListWrapper**

```
public class DocumentListWrapper {
List<DocumentList> documentListList;
```

}

**documentList**

```
public class DocumentList {
    //others field not needed
    int Id;
    String Name;

}
```

But when I call service always failed and go to failure method of my service and it's throws:

```
 D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
 D/Retrofit﹕ Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
 D/Retrofit﹕ X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
 D/Retrofit﹕ Date: Tue, 30 Jun 2015 06:33:26 GMT
 D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Length: 355
 D/Retrofit﹕ Connection: Keep-Alive
 D/Retrofit﹕ [{"CreateDate":null,"Creator":0,"Id":1,"LastModifiedDate":null,"Modifier":0,"Description":null,"Name":"test0"},{"CreateDate":null,"Creator":0,"Id":2,"LastModifiedDate":null,"Modifier":0,"Description":null,"Name":"test1"},{"CreateDate":null,"Creator":1,"Id":3,"LastModifiedDate":null,"Modifier":1,"Description":null,"Name":"test2"}]
D/Retrofit﹕ <--- END HTTP (355-byte body)
```

**Edited : **

Service :

```
 @GET("/DocumentTypeList1")
void documentTypeList1(
        @Query("userName") String userName,
        @Query("password") String password, Callback<DocumentListWrapper> callback);
```

serviceHelper class :

```
        public static final int TIMEOUT_CONNECTION = 6000;
    public static final int TIMEOUT_SOCKET = 30000;

    private static ServiceHelper instance = new ServiceHelper();
    RestAdapter restAdapter;
    IocService service;

    private ServiceHelper() {
        restAdapter = createAdapter();
        service = restAdapter.create(IocService.class);
    }

    public static ServiceHelper getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private RestAdapter createAdapter() {

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
        // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used.
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, TIMEOUT_SOCKET);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        return new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setClient(new ApacheClient(httpClient))
                .build();
    }
}

public void documentTypeList1(String userName,String password,Callback<DocumentListWrapper> callback){
        service.documentTypeList1(userName,password,callback);
```

and I call service with methods like this :

```
public void documentListType(){
    ServiceHelper.getInstance().documentTypeList1("userName", "password", new Callback<DocumentList>() {
        @Override
        public void success(DocumentListWrapper documentListWrapper, Response response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {

        }
    });
}
```

My question : Is something Wrong with my Object class or it's by service call or ... ?

Comment: It seems your Object class is ok. Could you show the Retrofit call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `List` callback for array response and it works fine.

```
@GET("/DocumentTypeList1")
void documentTypeList1(
        @Query("userName") String userName,
        @Query("password") String password, Callback<List<DocumentList>> callback);
```

Comment: My documentListWrapper does the same isn't it ?

Comment: idk, but maybe, if `DocumentListWrapper` works, json looks like `{ "documentListList": [...]}`